# Playback of 720x1280 shows color artifacts

Tags: kodi, osmc

While trying to stream my android phone's screen to Raspberry PI running Kodi (OSMC), I noticed that it couldn't play the H264 encoded video stream (with YUV420P pixel format) properly. It showed artefacts all over the place (pink/green vertical stripes).

Investigating it further, I noticed that this happens with any video of that resolution 720x1280. When the resolution is 1920x1080, the problem goes away. Now I wonder whether there is an option or workaround to fix this problem, or whether I always have to manually convert such videos to make them watchable.

Comment: What Android app are you using?

Comment: @goobering adb shell screenrecord

Comment: There are a lot of moving parts here. It could be your videos, especially if they've all been encoded using the same method. It could be whatever streaming component you're using in addition to screenrecord. It could be the streaming protocol you're using. It could be that your Android device doesn't natively support 1280x720. It could be the particular Kodi version you're using. It could be some horrible combination of all of the above. I'd maybe start by trying to find out if your Android supports 1280x720.

Comment: @goobering i took that video and resized it to fullhd or to HD+ and it worked. I took another working video and resized it to 720x1280 and it failed. Does that not point to the prohpem bring the reoslution and that the raspbpi hw decoder is not able to handle it somehow?

Comment: @goobering in addition the situation is the same for playing back the file locally vs streaming it. Clarification: 1280x720 *does* work (but doesn't match the phones resolution). What fails is 720x1280. Could it be that the height exceeds the display height of raspbpi and that this causes problems?

Comment: I've had a chance to do some testing. Unfortunately I can't replicate your problem. My sample clip is 720x1280, YUV420, MP4/AVC, 23.976fps, 225MB. I'm playing that back from an external mechanical hard drive attached by USB to a Pi 2 running OpenELEC 6.0.0, which uses Kodi 15.2. Are there any significant differences between your setup and mine?

Comment: @goobering hmm I usr OSMC. But I would think that wouldn't make a difference. I can try to upload a test video file so you can try my file. Alternatively could you please share your 720x1280 file so I can try to play it?

Comment: I used [this](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-20160201-git-b62825a-win64-static.7z) ffmpeg build against [this](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4) video file. I ran: ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4 -vf scale=720:1280 -aspect=9:16 resized.mp4 . I copied resized.mp4 to the Pi's external drive and opened it with Kodi. No issues.

Comment: @goobering I compared my video and the video of you (before conversion). And the outputs are for mine: "Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x1280, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc" and for yours: "Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1100 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)". I am unsure about the meaning of all those trailing numbers and what the "default" means though. Do you sense any problems here?

Comment: I also tried your conversion line, however it fails with "'aspect=9:16'", ffmpeg version 2.8.5. I tried your version with wine, but it still complains about the aspect option.

Comment: My fault! Screwed up the flag order. Should have been: ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_50mb.mp4 -aspect 9:16 -vf scale=720:1280 resized.mp4 . I can't see anything alarming in your comparison numbers. You're using H.264(High) while I'm using H.264(Main), but that shouldn't be disastrous.

Comment: @goobering weird. I tried that command line with your video and playing it back in my rasp pi 2 shows the color artifacts

Comment: Plausibly specific to your particular setup then - check your power supply and cabling, update/upgrade everything. Seriously consider testing a non-OSMC platform such as OpenELEC or even Raspbian, if only to rule that out as a factor.